# Twilio Call resource doesn't return all calls to and from a specific number

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I want to get all the calls that were made to and from a specific `active number`. Though I am able to get either calls `To` a number or calls that were made `From` this number. However I am not able to get all the calls including both TO and FROM this number.

I tried -- [this API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-call-logs/node) to get call logs.

Comment: I tried with Phone number Sid as well, but it returns the conversations of the whole account.

Comment: This should be the right function call. How many records are missing and do you see them in the logs? Maybe you need to increase the `limit` property or just paging to get all results.

Comment: I am getting all the logs but I need to make two API calls, one for fetching `incoming` calls and the other for `outgoing` calls. I want to fetch both the types of calls using one single API call. Looks like there is nothing like this, even the call logs on console show only `incoming` or `outgoing` call logs at a time. Lmk if have information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand the problem you are describing. This is not possible atm. So you need to trigger to separate request (or you use one request to fetch all log entries and filter on the client side).

Comment: following this documentation to get call logs https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-call-logs/node# but pagination is not working in this as in response I am not getting nextPageURI

Comment: It should be working, a missing nextPageURI usually means there is no next page. But it's probably best to ask a separate question here if you run into problems with the paging mechanism.